# I defined some things for my RPG, and it's not working

Tags: python

I've been working a bit on a Python text RPG as my first sort of mini-project to test my skills, but I've already run into a bit of a wall. Here's the script; first of all:

```
from time import sleep
import random
EXP = 0
EXPCap = 1
Lv = 1
ATK = 5
MATK = 5
DEF = 10
MDEF = 10
HP = 100
EATK = 0
EMATK = 0
EDEF = 0
EMDEF = 0
EHP = 0
MHP = 1
Ename = ("None")
fireorbcount = 0
waterorbcount = 0
earthorbcount = 0
ironcount = 0
windorbcount = 0
windsword = 0
firesword = 0
earthsword = 0
watersword = 0
movement = 1
burn = ("No")
poison = ("No")
Slash = ("UnLocked")
DoubleSlash = ("Locked")
Fireball = ("UnLocked")
FirePillar = ("Locked")
Battlecry = ("Locked")
def Slime():
    EHP = 90
    EATK = 5
    EDEF = 10
    EMATK = 5
    EMDEF = 2
    Ename = Slime
    def enemyatk():
        if movement == 1:
            if random.randint(0,100) >51:
                print("Slime uses Stomp!")
                HP = HP - (20 + EATK - (DEF / 3))
                sleep(0.2)
                print( name , "has" , HP , "HP out of" , MHP,"!")
                sleep(0.2)
            if random.randit(0,100) <50:
                print("Slime uses Piercing Stomp!")
                HP = HP - (20 + EATK)
                sleep(0.2)
                print( name , "has" , HP , "HP out of" , MHP,"!")
                sleep(0.2)
        else:
            movement = movement + 1
    def getdrops():
        print("You have defeated" , Ename,"!")
        sleep(0.1)
        print("You have recieved one water orb!")
        waterorbcount = waterorbcount + 1
    encounter()
def encounter():
     if DoubleSlash == ("UnLocked"):
         print("Double Slash")
     if FirePillar == ("UnLocked"):
         print("Fire Pillar")
     if Battlecry == ("Unlocked"):
         print("Battle Cry")
     atk_1 = input()
     if atk_1 == ("Slash"):
         EHP = EHP - (40 + ATK - (EDEF / 4))
         print( Ename , "has" , EHP , "HP remaining!")
         enemyatk()
         if HP <1:
             print("You have been defeated!")
             quit()
         if EHP <1:
             print("The enemy has died!")
             getdrops()
print("Please input your name")
name = input()
print("Welcome," , name , "to Pellandia! Please select an action.")
while 1 + 1 == 2:
    sleep(0.2)
    print("Check Items")
    sleep(0.2)
    print("Craft")
    sleep(0.2)
    print("Explore")
    sleep(0.2)
    print("Quit")
    choice = input()
    if choice == ("Quit"):
        quit()
    if choice == ("Check Items"):
        print("Fire Orbs:" , fireorbcount)
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Water Orbs:" , waterorbcount)
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Wind Orbs:" , windorbcount)
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Earth Orbs:" , earthorbcount)
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Iron:" , ironcount)
    if choice == ("Explore"):
        print("Where would you like to explore?")
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Plains")
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Caves")
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Lava Mountains")
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Underwater Abyss")
        sleep(0.2)
        print("Ishgria")
        explorec = input()
        if explorec == ("Plains"):
            Slime()
```

The slime function at the bottom, for whatever reason, isn't working. I've defined the encounter already, so I'm not sure why. The script just seems to stop and go back to the main menu (Explore, Check Items, ect).
Can someone please help me identify what's going on?

Comment: What do you want the function to return?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It looks like most of the code you posted is unrelated to your problem and not necessary to replicate it.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in a debugger yet?

Comment: `Slime` calls `encounter`, `encounter` waits for an input and if the input is not `"Slash"` you're back in your `while 1 + 1 == 2:`-loop.

Comment: Please get rid of all those global variables in your program. Use functions. Make sure that the functions get the needed values as parameters and give back values with `return`. You said this is your "first sort of mini-project". For the sake of your own sanity: Rewrite the code, this approach is doomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you enter the `Slime()`, then enter `encounter()` all while nothing is output.  How you are suppose to know to type "Slash" I'm not sure. If you don't it just jumps back out to main menu.  If you do type "Slash" you get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 123, in <module>
    Slime()
  File "game.py", line 63, in Slime
    encounter()
  File "game.py", line 75, in encounter
    EHP = EHP - (40 + ATK - (EDEF / 4))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'EHP' referenced before assignment
```

If you want to use the `Slime` local variables you probably should make it an object that is passed into encounter.